# Ragtag commands working partially

Tags: linux, vim, xterm, terminator

I've just installed ragtag and trying to edit an html.erb file on Terminator.

When I try the following:

```
foo<C-X>= it works and the result is foo<%= %>
```

But the commands bellow do not work:

```
foo<C-X><CR> or
foo<C-X><Space>
```

The strange thing is that `<C-X><CR>` works on xterm, and `<C-X><Space>` doesn't work.

Is it something that I need to configure in my terminal?

**EDIT**

The first time I try `foo<C-X><SPACE>` an error is shown `E29: No inserted text yet`. Next time I try it just goes to normal mode.

```
`foo<C-X><CR>` just goes to the next line keeping the insert mode.
```

Comment: Does any error come up or what? What do you mean by `dont work either` exactly?

Comment: I added more details =)

Comment: It works if I change the lines 67 and 68 of ragtag.vim to:

inoremap <silent> <buffer> <C-X>;
inoremap <silent> <buffer> <C-X>.

But I would be glad to know what happened, I may have similar problems in the futre.